# How to make the back button work after pushState in Chrome / Safari

Tags: google-chrome, safari, pushstate

I have an error handler in my single page app that reloads the page if the ajax request fails for some reason, displaying the error response to the user. With Chrome and Safari, a subsequent click of the back button will leave the user on the error page (though the url will be updated back to the original page.)

Minimal code to reproduce:

```
var missing_url = window.location.pathname + '/missing'
window.history.pushState({test:'test'}, 'new page', missing_url);
// Reloading will return the 404
window.location.reload();
```

Demo: http://bl.ocks.org/lrowe/raw/5551102/

Source: https://gist.github.com/lrowe/5551102

As far as I can tell this is nothing to do with caching, when clicking back nothing shows up in the network panel and I see the same behave when the browser cache is disabled.

Comment: Possible bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124528

Comment: And in webkit: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=80697